# Moving Controller as service to to other service on top level.....symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If I have a controller which is with the name space

```
      Src/ApiMap/ApiMapBundle/controller/Getapicontroller
           class GetApiController extends Controller {
           fitch data on the bases of entities define in entites classes and then save that data in in table
   and save it in database
}
```

Now I define this as service in

```
     App/config/service.yml
         services:
            app.get_controller:  
           class: ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\Controller\GetApiController
```

3rd I define a service class on the location

```
       app/container/getApi.php
```

Now I want to access this controller-service in this class I means in this service how can i access because if i use

```
         this->get function
```

in simple class what would i need for it.

the point is i can not move my logic to service bcz it is using entities and other stuff in controller i want to move this logic  to some 3rd class service... 
it location is right now

```
   src/container
           getapi.php
```

and its definition is right now...

```
 <?php
   namespace dino_container\GetApi;
  class GetApi {
          public function __construct() {
            i want to incorport this controller service in this class...
        }
```

Comment: Is this third class also a service?

Comment: yes it is simple class i want to incorport this controller in class

Comment: Please, add 3rd class code, I mean class signature and constructor + this class service definition from service.yml

Comment: it is just simple class no more. because later i want to call this class in commond service for define in crontab ...                                                class GetApiCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

Comment: Man, I asked you is this class a service - you said yes, now it turns to be that it is not. If it's not service - you'll need to manually create instance of that `getApi` class and pass all needed parameters/services in there. Actually to work with `$this->get` analogue in `getApi` class you need to pass container as a parameter for `getApi` class `__construct` method. And then implement `get` function in you class. It would look smth like this: `public function get($serviceName) { if ($this->container->has($serviceName)) { return $this->container->get(serviceName); } else {return null; } }`

Comment: @Ilya Yarkovets thankx for your answer. now when i define a main controller class as service and when i call  $container = new ContainerBuilder(); in some other place  and then when i try this $newsletterManager = $container->get('app.get_controller');   it give me error that   " 'The service definition "app.get_controller" does not exist.' " why it does not Recognize the service which i already define.. can you guide me here? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you actually using the Symfony 2 framework or just some of the components?  I ask because new ContainerBuilder makes no sense within the context of the framework.  I might add that injecting a controller into another service does not make much sense either.  Hard to follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am using symfony2 framework 2.7 version. i have problem i just want to call this controller as service. how can i call it.  in offical docuement they show that u can call it through $this->forward('app.hello_controller:indexAction', array('name' => $name)); but i do not know how. but whereever i call this it give me error that forward is not recognizable.....

Comment: my main problem is i want to call this controller in some  class GetApiCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand... because i need to access this controller from console and It need to be define in crontab for periodic call

Comment: @zahid, If you just want to see controller, defined as a service, from console command, everything is simple. Firstly, if your command extends `ContainerAwareCommand` - there is no need to use `ContainerBuilder` (as there you must register your services by hand), in such command you can use `$controller = $this->getContainer()->get('app.get_controller');`

Comment: I define this function here in the GetApiCommand class of                                         protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)    {//$command = $this->getApplication()->find('cron:getapi');
     $controller = $this->getContainer()->get('app.get_controller');  now when i run this commond on commond prompt ::: php app/console cron:getapi... it just run but this controller is not executed. bcz once it execute it must to give me output of inerstion records in database. when i run it from rout in browser it do that.... any idea what is missing i am here

Comment: But you haven't called any method from controller after getting it from container, as I see :) Just call something: `$controller->methodName();` where `methodName` is your method name which you need to call.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMapApiData\vendor\symfony\
symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 291
[2016-01-29 14:44:18] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Call to a member function has() on null {"type":1,"file"
:"D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ProjectMapApiData\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\
Controller\\Controller.php","line":291,"level":-1,"stack":[]}
this error i am getting now when i call this method

Comment: when i run it fom the browser with specific rout it fine.. it not give any error

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Error: Call to a member function has() on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we had this conversation before.

It makes no sense to try calling a controller method from a command.  A controller method's job is to convert a Request into a Response.  Commands have no request object nor would they know what to do with a Response object.

Instead you want to share functionality between a controller and a command by extracting the functionality into it's own service.  You then access that service from both the command and the controller.

```
# services.yml
my_service:
  class: MyService
  arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

# Controller
public function myAction(Request $request) 
{
  $myService = $this->container->get('my_service');
  $myService->doSomethingShared();

# Command
public function execute()
{
  $myService = $this->container->get('my_service');
  $myService->doSomethingShared();
```

Comment: this own service i means this cammond functionaliy where should i define??..  you saw the structure of my controller where should i define this service that i can access it. because i think it would be fiine that i call it in service and then i call that service in commond prompt??? will it be good or not ??

Comment: currently i define this controller as service so i can call it in another service? and then call that service in commond prompt?

Comment: No need to define the controller as a service until you understand what services are.  Again, it makes no sense to try calling a controller from someplace else so don't do it.  Move the database stuff that you want to share into it's own service then have both the controllers and the commands access the service.

Comment: should i define this service inside bundle or above the bundles ?

Comment: Either way is fine.  From your posted code it seems that you are not following the Symfony framework naming conventions.  I would suggest creating a new Symfony project and try to fit your code into it but if you are comfortable with your setup then put the source code wherever you want.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Notice: Undefined property: ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\Command\GetApiCommand::$container .  it give this error when i try to call any service function in the command.php which is basically a function for commond running.. any idea what is wrong

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container